# Ajax function called twice when clicking a button

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I've seen a couple of similar questions here but I couldn't fix this problem. It seems not be a bid deal because eventually it works, but trying to display a hidden div (imitating a popup) using Ajax when clicking a button if I debug I can see the controller in the method (ConfirmMaxBid) is called twice (even more I feel sometimes even more times, and mixing the flow through the code, i.e going back and forth).

Here's the view

```
@model UI.Models.BidOnAuctionViewModel
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/BidAndMaxBidConfirmation.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@{
   var disableButton = Model.AuctionOpen ? "" : "bid-btn-disabled";     
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("ConfirmMaxBid", "Lot"))
{
  <fieldset>
    <div class="lotdetail-maxbid-row">
        <label>Your Max Bid</label>
        @*<input id="Amount" class="radius2 text-box single-line valid" type="text" name="Amount" data-val-required="The Amount field is required." data-val-number="The field Amount must be a number." data-val="true">*@
        @if (Model.AuctionOpen)
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Amount, new {@class = "radius2 text-box single-line valid"})
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Amount, new {@class = "radius2 text-box single-line valid", @disabled = "disabled"})
        }
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="autobidButton" value="Increase Max bid" class="btn btn-level2 btn-maxbid @disableButton" />
  </fieldset>

  <div id="autoBidConfirmation" class="lotdetail-modal" style="display: none;"> 
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AuctionId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AutobidAmount)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AuctionEventId)
    <h4 id="confirmationMessage"></h4>
    <span id="returnedCorrectedAmount" class="lotdetail-modal-msg"></span>
    <input name="button" value="Place bid" type="submit" class="btn btn-level2" />
    <input id="cancelAutoBid" name="button" value="Cancel" type="submit" class="btn btn-level2 btn-cancel" />
  </div>
}
```

And here's the script's function called when document.ready

```
$('#autobidButton').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var model =
        {
            AuctionEventId: $('#AuctionEventId').val(),
            AuctionId: $('#AuctionId').val(),
            Amount: $('#Amount').val()
        };
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Lot/ConfirmMaxBid",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        success: function (data) {
            var amount = "$" + data.AutobidAmount;
            $('#returnedCorrectedAmount').html(amount);
            $('#AutobidAmount').val(data.AutobidAmount);
            $('#confirmationMessage').text(data.AutobidConfirmationMessage);
            $('#autoBidConfirmation').show();
        }
    });
});
```

And finally this is the method (the part is called twice at least, to avoid this question be too long)

```
public ActionResult ConfirmMaxBid(string button, BidOnAuctionViewModel model)
    {
        if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var confirmationMessage = "Confirm your bid";
            var correctedAmount = model.Amount;
            if (!CheckMaxBidFitsIncrementTier(model.Amount, model.AuctionEventId))
            {
                confirmationMessage = "This bid can't be placed, do you want to place the following instead?";
                correctedAmount = CalculateNextBidAmountForWrongMaxAmount(model.Amount, model.AuctionEventId);
            }

            return Json(new
            {
                AutobidAmount = correctedAmount,
                model.AuctionId,
                model.AuctionEventId,
                AutobidConfirmationMessage = confirmationMessage
            });
        }

        if (button == "Place bid")
        {
          //Here's the code to do the stuff when confirming in the partial view
```

Any idea why this happens?

Thanks in advance

Update

After placing some alerts (quite primitive way of debugging, I guess) I see that the method is called again just after the last line of the success function (after $('#autoBidConfirmation').show();)

Comment: How are you including your JS? is it inline in the body somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your document is probably ready multiple times after asyncronous post-backs.

Try something like:

```
$(document).ready(OnDocumentReady);

function OnDocumentReady()
{
     $("#autobidButton")
          .unbind("click", AutoBidFunction)
          .click(AutoBidFunction);
}

function AutoBidFunction(e)
{
    // Code Here
}
```

Comment: The event only happens once, regardless of post-backs.

Comment: well, I'm struggling with the solution cause I can't make it work. But I put an alert inside document.ready and it's actually called twice, so I think the answer is right.The Js is not inline, Kevin. The script is inside the BidAndMaxBidConfirmation.js referenced in the view

Comment: Yep, but I think you're right Kevin, the event only happens once even if the documentready happens more than once. Is this right?

Comment: Thanks both, jtimperley solution worked fine (I wasn't writing it correctly, not the sharpest tool in the box). Although to be honest I still don't understand why after the call back it was triggered again (the alert about document.ready didn't happen at that moment and more weirdly to me the button was clicked just once)